# Does a relation (aggregation, composition) replace an attribute?

Tags: uml

I'm pretty new at UML modelling so bear with me.

Say I have a class with an attribute `students` that is a list of `Student` instances. I have set an aggregation relation to the `Student` class which is also in the diagram. Does this relation *replace* an attribute entry such as `#students : Student[]` in the container class, or can the attribute and relation co-exist?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 15):

Short answer: Can the attribute and relationship both exist? No...

But **if your classes are software classes** you may have many choices for showing them:

[image]

But **if your classes are not sofware classes and you model the domain** you should be more carefully to show an entity as an attribute or class. Generally if the entity is complex type, it is shown as seperate class. But that is not a rule: depends on context.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An attribute helps to identify the structure of the object.  Aggregation gives a high level overview that the object will contain one (or more) of another type.  Neither replaces, but instead shows the relationship between the object types.

Answer (score 1):

You generally do not have attributes of a user-defined (or any complex) class. You certainly don't show an attribute AND an association for the same thing in UML. If I understand your situation, you're in need of an association (or aggregation/composition)... And play with the multiplicities to get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Why is it that one generally does not have attributes of a user-defined class?

Comment: Because that is exactly what associations are for. UML has separate notation for user-defined types.