# Are only Object Types Strings etc. considered as aggregates

Tags: java, aggregation

Let's consider following:

```
class bambi {
  //...some code
}
```

```
class rambo {
  //...some code
}
```

```
class coco_jambo {
  //...some code
}
```

```
class A{
    int a;
    boolean b;
    String c;
    bambi e;

    rambo some_method(coco_jambo par){}

}
```

are only `String c` and `bambi a` considered to be aggregates of `class A`? In other words when I am making an UML-Diagramm represantation of Aggregation of  A am I only going to draw `bambi e` and `String c` as "parts" of `A`? if so, why are primitive data types not considered as aggregates (parts) of `class A`?

What about when a method is returning an object type or taking one as a parameter, will `rambo` and `coco_jambo` also be considered as aggregates (parts) of `A` ?

Comment: I think you can ignore a, b and c from your UML diagram as those types are not representing entities in your domain

Comment: rambo and coco_jambo are not considered as aggregates as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a relation (aggregation, composition) replace an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797448/does-a-relation-aggregation-composition-replace-an-attribute)